# Alternative text for different views of the same product

Tags: html, web, accessibility, uiaccessibility, alt

When a group of images are presented to show different photographic views of a product(front view, side view, zoomed view etc) especially beneficial for sighted users, what should the alternative text for the images be like? Is it sufficient to add alt text for the first image to read something like "Different photographic views of product X" and leave the alt empty for the remaining images in the group.

I am assuming that adding alt text for each image would be unnecessary noise for SR users but would like to learn from experts if the alt text for each image would be valuable or not.

Comment: Good question.  This isn't really an answer, but it's the closest thing to an answer that I could find. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58217596/best-practice-for-image-title-and-alt-text-for-accessibility

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57901256/2702894 is more appropriate to answer this question, more than happy to throw more info down as looking back at that answer it isn't as clear as I make things now but I think you should get the gist.

Answer (score 1):

obligitory not an expert but alt text for images should convey the purpose of an image rather than the actual content of an image.

In your example, for someone without sight, knowing that the images are various photos of product X are relatively meaningless unless they know what product X looks like (not likely).

You may be better off using an alt text such as "this photo of product X shows that it performs its function in X way".

Also if it's multiple images, unless each image is showing a different function or feature of the product I would say more alt text probably won't help and should be left out.

This advice is all pretty subjective depending on your product but I hope it helps.

Ref:
https://usability.yale.edu/web-accessibility/articles/images